# UK Visitor visa - arriving together

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

My partner has a UK visitor visa issued. He said he would travel with me into entering the UK. That is our ideal plan but the best airplanes pass by USA which he cannot enter (unless transit visa which is complicated to get).

In that case, I am thinking about going on a different plane to him and him arriving solo. Will it make a difference when he has to go through entry clearance?

Answer (score 1):

As long as he holds a visa and valid documents/copy submitted to get the visitor visa, it is not a problem.

(docs like : stay address, marriage certificate, return ticket, funds etc..)

Should not be a problem at all if he can demonstrate the situation.